# horizontal centering the element

Tags: css, alignment, margin

There are many situation that horizontal centering not work. I checked many solution, but no one works for me.
I have some two wrappers, and i use margin: 0 auto; here
For clear illustration you may see the jsfiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/JdtKV/

with width: 100%, it works.
actually I want a fixed-length block to stay in the middle bottom.

There is another problem with the similar code here during my development:
[Different CSS bottom placement for Firefox and Chrome with table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455031/different-css-bottom-placement-for-firefox-and-chrome-with-table)

here is my html:

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class= 'container border'>
        <div class="container-content border">
            I should be in the middle
            <div class="container-content-bottom border">
               I also want go to middle
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css here:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.container{
  display: table;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container-content{
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.container-content-bottom{
    margin:0 auto; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.border{
    border: solid 1px #00f;
}
```

Comment: for `margin: 0 auto;` to work, a width should be set for the element. If it's 100%, how can it be centered? Or if you want to center the contents of the element, use `text-align: center;` instead.

Comment: I tried set width to it, but the margin things didn't work for it. with width:100%; and text-align it works well :), so I still want to know why this margin does not work for me

Comment: Ah I didn't notice you were using `position: absolute;`, why not `text-align: center;` ?

Comment: @xFortyFourx text-align didn't work for it o:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue to use "position: absolute" you can define a value for "left" to center the container-content-bottom div.

```
.container-content-bottom{
width:50%;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:25%;
}
```

From there you can define a width for the div and change the value of left until it is centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/JdtKV/2/

You could also just add "width: 100%;" if that is the result you are looking for.

```
.container-content-bottom{
width:100%;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: the first method works well, but why the margin things doesn't work for it? I cannot thought of reason .

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't work because of "position: absolute;" when an element is absolutely positioned it gets its positioning/coordinates from "left", "right", "top", and "bottom". Those values overwrite margins and padding. The default value for left is 0 if you do not define anything else so that probably why it was showing up in the bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

This will center the text. Not sure if that's the desired result. If not, you might want to make a mockup of what you want in Paint or something.

CSS:

```
.container-content-bottom {
    wdith: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need "position: absolute". Moreover I put a width < 100% to the div, which you want to put into the middle.

Here is the part of css I altered:

```
.container-content-bottom{
    margin:0 auto; /*try use width:100% instead, strange effect happens*/
    width:50%;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:center;` and `margin: 0 auto; display: block`.

If it's a block or an image, you should apply margin properties, and display it as a block (as shown above)

Example:

```
.block {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

If it's just text, you use `text-align: center`.

P.S: More info can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/JdtKV/1/)**</kbd>

Just add `right:0; left:0; margin:auto;`

Change styles of your `.container-content-bottom` to

```
.container-content-bottom{
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: it is the similiar way with width 100%, actually I want a fixed-length block to stay in the middle bottom